# Проблема с высотой элемента

Tags: css

Есть `div`'ы с классом `row`, в них несколько `div` класса `column` c `display: inline-block`, (так сказать таблица) они могут быть разной высоты в зависимости от контента, поэтому у .row'ов тоже разная высота, проблема в том, что некоторые элементы закрашены, и видно что они по высоте не до конца, как заставить работать `height: 100%` у элементов `.column`?
[image]

Comment: На Ваш вопрос будет проще дать ответ если Вы выложите пример на [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Можно для **row** задать **display: table-row;**, а для **column** - **display: table-cell;**. Тогда получим [такой результат][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Jw4Nb/

Comment: табличные display нельзя

Comment: @Sleepless, Только CSS? JS тоже нельзя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height 100%` будет работать если у родителя высота задана явно, чего в данном случае нет. В общем в голову приходит только такой вариант:
http://jsfiddle.net/hdSMh/1/ .

```css
.row{
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        ololo
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col">
        ololo
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col">
        ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo ololo 
    </div><!--
    -->
</div>
```